# Filter ExtensionAttribute & Add to Group

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

Looking to lookup users by EmployeeID and filter through their ExtensionAttributes and assign to AzureADGroup if filter matches

So far I've tried

```
Get-AzureADUserExtension -filter{ExtensionAttribute5 -eq "Test"} | %{Add- 
AzureADGroupMember GroupTest01 $_.EmployeeID}
```

This is the error message I get

```
Get-AzureADUserExtension : A parameter cannot be found that matches 
parameter name 'filter'.
At line:1 char:26
```

Comment: @JoyWang sorry for delay! got busy, but i will test it tonight or tomorrow morning and will let you know!

Comment: I apologize for delay, became very busy, but now i'm cleared up. I ran the script and i got a null objectID error for line2: Get-AzureADUserExtension : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'ObjectId' because it is null.
At line:2 char:49 @JoyWang

Comment: this is the script i'm running: $ObjectId = (Get-AzureADUser | Where-Object {$_.ExtensionProperty.employeeId -eq "54312"}).ObjectId
$extension = Get-AzureADUserExtension -ObjectId $ObjectId
if($extension.extensionAttribute8 -eq '12345'){
Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId "xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxx" -RefObjectId $ObjectId
} @JoyWang

Comment: @JoyWang any update?

Comment: No, it works fine on my side.

Comment: @JoyWang the account i have and the extensionattribute im trying to read is pulled from onprem ad extensionattributes 1 - 15 and the extensionattributes for this account can only be viewed in the Microsoft Graph API. could this be the reason why it's not working out?

Comment: @JoyWang so, i would need to log into https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer and then run the script https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/xxxx@xxxxx.com?$select=onpremisesextensionattributes in order to see onPremisesExtensionAttributes....im thinking this may be the reason it may result into 'null'. what do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the command below, make sure the user is not already existing in the group, otherwise you will get an error.

```
$ObjectId = (Get-AzureADUser | Where-Object {$_.ExtensionProperty.employeeId -eq "123"}).ObjectId

$extension = Get-AzureADUserExtension -ObjectId $ObjectId

if($extension.<extension name> -eq 'testvalue222'){

Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId "<group objectid>" -RefObjectId $ObjectId

}
```